# Animate a progress tag with pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, progress-bar

What I'm looking to do is basically have the progress bar go from value 1-100 in one second.
It doesn't depend on an actual process status.

This is my effort so far, I can't see why it's having no effect.

```
<progress id="progBar" value="0" max="100"> </progress> 

setInterval(function(){

             var pb = document.getElementById("progBar");

                            if (pb.value < 100){
                   pb.value = pb.value + 1;
                }


                },10);
```

Any Ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine http://jsfiddle.net/KqpUs/

Comment: Not sure if a previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22393492/progress-bar-wobble-effect can help you

Comment: Please have a look following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559268/javascript-progress-bar/41195688#41195688

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you use mainly CSS to do this.

```
div.progress-bar
{
    /* Your style attributes */

    transition: width 1s;
    -ms-transition: width 1s;
    -o-transition: width 1s;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s;
    -moz-transition: width 1s;
}
```

Then in your javascript, set the width to whatever you want. For example (using jQuery):

```
$('div.progress-bar').width('100%');
```

CSS will animate it automatically.

If you wish to support older browsers (i.e. < Internet Explorer 10), then you'll have to do that in JavaScript. I'd recommend jQuery for that since it's handled for you:

```
$('div.progress-bar').animate({width: "100%"}, 1000);
```

If you don't care about older browser support, just stick with the CSS way of doing it. jQuery will still use JavaScript for animation even if CSS animation support is available.